# Getting unexpected values in postman response (Asp.net Core WebApi)

Tags: c#, .net-core, webapi

I have created a WebApi in Asp.net Core but getting some unexpected values in response.

Event $id and $values are not there in model classes.

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "$values": [
    {
        "$id": "2",
        "tenentId": 21,
        "language": 1,
        "formId": "EmployeeGrid",
        "formName": "Employee Grid",
        "headerName": "KU Employee Main Grid",
        "subHeader": "Main Grid of the Employee Master",
        "navigation": "MainMenu>View Contact>Add New Contact",
        "remarks": "",
        "status": "",
        "formTitleDts": {
            "$id": "3",
            "$values": []
        }
    },
    {
        "$id": "4",
        "tenentId": 21,
        "language": 2,
        "formId": "EmployeeGrid",
        "formName": "Employee Grid",
        "headerName": "KU Employee Main Grid",
        "subHeader": "Main Grid of the Employee Master",
        "navigation": "MainMenu>View Contact>Add New Contact",
        "remarks": "",
        "status": "",
        "formTitleDts": {
            "$id": "5",
            "$values": []
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea how can get a normal response please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide some code with the expected response vs the unexpected response

Comment: @MernaMustafa thanks for your response. this should be a normal array like this {.........}   `{
        "$id": "2",
        "tenentId": 21,
        "language": 1,
        "formId": "EmployeeGrid",
        "formName": "Employee Grid",
        "headerName": "KU Employee Main Grid",
        "subHeader": "Main Grid of the Employee Master",
        "navigation": "MainMenu>View Contact>Add New Contact",
        "remarks": "",
        "status": "",
        "formTitleDts": {
            "$id": "3",
            "$values": []
        }
    },`

Comment: If there's a problem, it's going to be in the code that generates this. As written there's no way for us to help you.

Comment: hi shakir, it would be helpful if you could provide a [mcve]. you should at least provide the code on how the json is made.

Comment: It would be good if you can provide model structure  which is result of your API.

Comment: @ShakirAli did you ever solve this? My API was working fine until I added the .Core.Proxies library for lazy loading... even after removing the library the issue has no gone away. Nothin else has changed in the code but I can't get it back to how it was before.